# Dynamically added buttons (using jQuery) have to be clicked twice to fire the click event already bound to the button

Tags: jquery, button, click

I dynamically add a select button that can be clicked to select a given contact from the list being appended to a table.

I have to click anywhere in the document before I can click on the dynamically added buttons. Clearly the bind events for the dynamic buttons are not binding until after the first click.

BTW, in the current version of the function I bind a click event to the body of the document for each dynamic button, and then see if the event target is the relevant dynamic button, at which time I trigger the desired function to pass back the selected contact.  I switched to this approach on the advice given to someone else experiencing the same thing I'm describing here.  Before this implementation, I had a very traditional $J("#btnId").bind('click', { .... }, function (event) { ... }); approach to bind the click event, which resulted in the same experience of having to click twice before the click event would fire on dynamic buttons.  I've also come at this from other angles, using jQuery's .bind, .live, .delegate approaches, and in all cases I had to click twice before the button's click event would actually fire.

```
function PickContacts() {
    if ($J("#tblCp").length > 0) {
        var broad = $J("#chkCpBroad").prop("checked");
        var contactType = GetCheckBoxListValues("divCpContactType");
        var contactId = "";
        if ($J("#txtCpContactId").length > 0) {
            contactId = $J("#txtCpContactId").val();
        }
        var contactName = $J("#txtCpContactName").val();
        var firstName = $J("#txtCpFirstName").val();
        var lastName = $J("#txtCpLastName").val();
        var email = $J("#txtCpEmail").val();
        var allMatches = $J("#chkCpAllMatches").prop("checked");
        var rows = ParseInts($J("#txtCpRowsReturned").val(), 10);
        if (rows === 0) {
            rows = 15;
        }
        var crmSeatsOnly = false;
        if (cpCrmSeatsOnly !== null && cpCrmSeatsOnly === "Y") {
            crmSeatsOnly = true;
        }
        var tbl = $J("#tblCpResults");
        tbl.empty();
        if (contactId !== "" || contactName !== "" || firstName !== "" || lastName !== "" || email !== "") {
            $J.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ClientBin/Contact.asmx/ContactPicker",
                data: "{'broad':" + broad + ",'contactType':'" + contactType + "','contactId':'" + contactId + "','contactName':'" + contactName + "','firstName':'" + firstName + "','lastName':'" + lastName + "','email':'" + email + "','allMatches':" + allMatches + ",'crmSeatsOnly':" + crmSeatsOnly + ",'rows':" + rows + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                context: tbl,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.d !== "TIME OUT") {
                        var JObject = ParseJson(result.d);
                        if (JObject !== null) {
                            if (JObject.RESULT[0].SUCCESS) {
                                var alternatingRow = false;
                                var c = JObject.CONTACT;
                                for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                                    var trStyle = "rowstyleNoBorder";
                                    if (alternatingRow) {
                                        trStyle = "alternatingrowstyleNoBorder";
                                        alternatingRow = false;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        alternatingRow = true;
                                    }

                                    this.append('<tr class="' + trStyle + '"><td><span id="lblCpContactId' + i + '">' + c[i].CONTACT_ID + '</span></td><td><span id="lblCpContactName' + i + '">' + c[i].CONTACT_NAME + '</span></td><td><span id="lblCpFirstName' + i + '">' + c[i].FIRST_NAME + '</span></td><td><span id="lblCpLastName' + i + '">' + c[i].LAST_NAME + '</span></td><td valign="top"><input type="submit" id="btnCpSelect' + i + '" value="' + $J("#hdnCpTransSelect").val() + '" title="' + $J("#hdnCpTransSelectContact").val() + '" /></td></tr>');

                                    $J("body").bind('click', { index: i, contactId: c[i].CONTACT_ID, contactName: c[i].CONTACT_NAME, firstName: c[i].FIRST_NAME, lastName: c[i].LAST_NAME }, function (event) {
                                        if ($J(event.target).is("#btnCpSelect" + event.data.index)) {
                                            SelectContact(event.data.contactId, event.data.contactName, event.data.firstName, event.data.lastName);
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    // Copy button css styling from an existing on page button by passing the IDs for both buttons to the CopyBtnStyle fn.
                                    CopyBtnStyle("btnCpSelect" + i, "btnCpClose");
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                this.append('<tr><td><span id="lblCpNoRows">' + JObject.RESULT[0].FEEDBACK + '</span></td></tr>');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        TimeOut();
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    WsFail(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wall of text alert! A nice, short, concise example with the least amount of irrelevant code coupled with to-the-point questions usually yield quicker and better answers.

Comment: Tks for the advice DarthJDG... I've never posted on stack flow and probably over did it w/ my first post of the question.  I've shortened accordingly to hopefully garner more reads.

Comment: +1 for revising your post, welcome to SO! Binding events like that is not good practice, you should definitely use `.delegate()`, which does a quite similar thing, taking advantage of event bubbling and checking the original selector against `event.target`. You should also not bind a separate event for every row, especially if you've got paging, you might end up with hundreds of unused but bound events firing at every click. There must be something else going on there, are you sure you don't have any events conditionally calling `event.stopPropagation()` further up the DOM tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright... I got to the bottom of things here.  I'm not sure technically why this is a problem, and maybe one of the more knowledgeable contributors up here could explain it for me, but my problem with having to click these dynamic buttons twice to trigger the click event was caused by the fact that I'd wired up my "PickContacts" JS function to be called on the keyup and blur events of my text input fields in the form.

While obviously a bit redundant, I am just not sure why this would be a problem, as before I call the WS method to retrieve the contact list, I do empty the table where the results sent back by the WS method are displayed.  So, I would've assumed that along with the table rows and their elements being removed from the DOM, so too would the click event that had been bound to the dynamic button on key up or on blur (whichever came first).

All I can say with certainty is what I can observe, and that is that after I remove either one of the events from the text input fields, leaving either of the other in place, my problem of having to click twice before getting the button's click event to fire is resolved.

If there is anyone out there that knows technically why by binding both of those events to call this function that builds the list would create the problem, I'd love to better understand it on a fundamental level.

In any event, I thank again the attention given by both PetersonDidIt and DarthJDG.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things you can do to make this work better.  I reworked the code some and added a lot of comments to try to explain why I made the changes: http://jsbin.com/ipuki5/2/edit

or mass code block:

```
// Create an easy to edit template for our row
var contactsRowtmpl = '<tr class="%trStyle%"><td><span id="lblCpContactId%index%">%CONTACT_ID%</span></td>'+
    '<td><span id="lblCpContactName%index%">%CONTACT_NAME%</span></td>'+
    '<td><span id="lblCpFirstName%index%">%FIRST_NAME%</span></td>'+
    '<td><span id="lblCpLastName%index%">%LAST_NAME%</span></td>'+
    '<td valign="top"><input type="submit" id="btnCpSelect%index%" class="CpSelect" value="%value%" title="%title%" /></td></tr>';

// Very simple templating function
function template( tmpl, data ) {
  return tmpl.replace(/%(\w*)%/g,function(){ return data[ arguments[1] ] || "";});
}

// Cache the table selector 
var tblCpResults = $J("#tblCpResults");
// Use delegate to bind the click event to for all input.CpSelet  
tblCpResults.delegate("click", ".CpSelect", function (event) {
  // prevent the default action of the click event
  event.preventDefault();
  // retrive the data from the row
  var data = $( this ).closest("tr").data("contact");
  // Select the contact
  SelectContact(data.contactId, data.contactName, data.firstName, data.lastName);
});

function PickContacts() {
    if ($J("#tblCp").length > 0) {
        var broad = $J("#chkCpBroad").prop("checked");
        var contactType = GetCheckBoxListValues("divCpContactType");
        var contactId = "";
        if ($J("#txtCpContactId").length > 0) {
            contactId = $J("#txtCpContactId").val();
        }
        var contactName = $J("#txtCpContactName").val();
        var firstName = $J("#txtCpFirstName").val();
        var lastName = $J("#txtCpLastName").val();
        var email = $J("#txtCpEmail").val();
        var allMatches = $J("#chkCpAllMatches").prop("checked");
        var rows = ParseInts($J("#txtCpRowsReturned").val(), 10);
        if (rows === 0) {
            rows = 15;
        }
        var crmSeatsOnly = false;
        if (cpCrmSeatsOnly !== null && cpCrmSeatsOnly === "Y") {
            crmSeatsOnly = true;
        }

        tblCpResults.empty();
        if (contactId !== "" || contactName !== "" || firstName !== "" || lastName !== "" || email !== "") {
            $J.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ClientBin/Contact.asmx/ContactPicker",
                // Use a normal object here much easier to maintain
                data: {
                  'broad': broad,
                  'contactType': contactType,
                  'contactId': contactId,
                  'contactName': contactName,
                  'firstName': firstName,
                  'lastName': lastName,
                  'email': email,
                  'allMatches': allMatches,
                  'crmSeatsOnly': crmSeatsOnly,
                  'rows': rows
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.d === "TIME OUT") {
                      TimeOut();
                      return;
                    }
                    var JObject = ParseJson(result.d),
                        // Cache these selectors so we don't have to reselect them in the for loop
                        hdnCpTransSelect = $J("#hdnCpTransSelect"),
                        hdnCpTransSelectContact = $J("#hdnCpTransSelectContact");
                    if (JObject !== null) {
                        if (!JObject.RESULT[0].SUCCESS) {
                          tblCpResults.append('<tr><td><span id="lblCpNoRows">' + JObject.RESULT[0].FEEDBACK + '</span></td></tr>');
                          return;
                        }
                        var c = JObject.CONTACT;
                        // Create an empty jQuery object to stuff all of the rows in
                        var rows = $();
                        for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                          c[ i ].trStyle = ( i % 2 ) ? "alternatingrowstyleNoBorder" : "rowstyleNoBorder";
                          c[ i ].index = i;
                          c[ i ].value = hdnCpTransSelect.val();
                          c[ i ].title = hdnCpTransSelectContact.val();

                          // Use the template function to handle creating our row
                          var row = template( contactsRowtmpl, c[ i ] );
                          // Add the contacts data to the row so we can retrive it later
                          $.data( row, "contact", c[ i ] );
                          // add the row to the rows jQuery object
                          rows = rows.add( row );
                          // Why do you need to copy the btn style? seems like this could be improved on.
                          CopyBtnStyle("btnCpSelect" + i, "btnCpClose");
                        }
                        // Now that we are done looping add all the rows to the dom.
                        tblCpResults.append( rows );
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    WsFail(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give the bad news first. I still have to click anywhere in the document, and then click the button before the click event triggers. So, my core issue remains. But, I give you serious props for cleaning up my routine. And, I _love_ the template concept. In the portal I'm helping to develop, I build lots of dynamic UL's, table rows, repeater divs, etc. And, in many cases, the same template could serve multiple dynamic lists. So, thanks much for teaching me a thing or two here. I'll now investigate DarthJDG's other tips WRT my need to click twice to trigger the click events.